# navbar logo shifts down when collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The logo icon shifts down when I collapse the page. It covers the first option of the collapsed navbar menu.

Is there anyway to have the logo and the collapse button on the same line?

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gastro</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
    "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse"
            data-target = ".navbar-collapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         </div>
         <a class="navbar-brand logo-nav"> 
            <%= link_to image_tag('nblogo.jpg'),   '#', id: "logo" %> 
          </a>

          <div class = "navbar-collapse collapse ">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Home",      '#' %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Menu",      '#' %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "About",     '#' %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "VIP",       '#' %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
    <!-- My Carousel
    ============================================================= -->


  <%= yield %>

</html>
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

.nav {
  margin-top: -55px;
  width: auto;
}

#logo {
  height: auto;
}

.navbar .brand {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the image in the post.

Comment: I did. There is a link right there next to screenshots...

Comment: Include the code and image _in this question._

Comment: I can't do that as I need 10 reputation. This is my first question. Thanks for being so friendly and downvoting this.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll add them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navbar-brand` needs to go inside the `navbar-header` like so...

```
  <div class="navbar-header">
     <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand logo-nav">Logo</a>
  </div>
```

Also, you should use `navbar-right` instead of `pull-right` on the `navbar-nav`. Unless you want the links pushed to the right side when collapsed.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it in collapse. Thank you! Now my problem is when it isn't collapsed.

edit: I'm going to try to figure it out first.

Comment: No prob, please mark as the answer, add another comment below if you put in another question, ill take a look at it.

Comment: Yay! I figured it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`navbar-brand` class has width `100%` by default, so on resize it covers the whole width of the display. Try and edit this class to

```
.navbar-brand {
    width:80% !important;
}
```